# Clicking on EditText does absolutely nothing and cursor stays at end

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, focus

How do I get it to open up the keyboard on click and change the cursor position when the user clicks within the text? I'm sure it's something simple, but I've tried setting `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to true, `enabled`, `textIsSelectable`, and nothing has worked. Have also tried using the following in my code:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.showSoftInput(typeField, 0);
```

My .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/softGreen"
    android:textColor="@color/darkBlue"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
    tools:context="com.angelwing.buddyup.ChatActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/softBlue"
        android:title="Hey"
        app:theme="@style/MyTheme"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Sample Text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sendButton"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/typeField"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/edittext_border"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/typeField"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="send"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:textOn="Sun"
        android:textOff="Sun"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/weekend_toggle_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/sundayButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:textOn="M"
        android:textOff="M"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/weekday_toggle_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sundayButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sundayButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sundayButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
        android:id="@+id/mondayButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:textOn="T"
        android:textOff="T"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/weekday_toggle_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mondayButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mondayButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mondayButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
        android:id="@+id/tuesdayButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:textOn="W"
        android:textOff="W"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/weekday_toggle_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tuesdayButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tuesdayButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tuesdayButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
        android:id="@+id/wednesdayButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:textOn="Th"
        android:textOff="Th"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/weekday_toggle_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wednesdayButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wednesdayButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/wednesdayButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
        android:id="@+id/thursdayButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:textOn="F"
        android:textOff="F"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/weekday_toggle_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thursdayButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thursdayButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thursdayButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
        android:id="@+id/fridayButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:textOn="Sat"
        android:textOff="Sat"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/weekend_toggle_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fridayButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fridayButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fridayButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/saturdayButton" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sundayButton"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edittext"
        android:id="@+id/messageListView"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/saturdayButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/saturdayButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/saturdayButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/setButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My java file:

```
package com.angelwing.buddyup;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar bar;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    Button sendButton;
    EditText typeField;

    String otherUserID;
    String buddyID;
    String buddyName;

    String thisUserName;
    String thisUserID;

    ChatArrayAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Message> allMessages;

    DatabaseReference convoRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

//        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
//        typeField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeField);
//
//        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
//        if (view != null)
//        {
//            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//            im.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
//        }
//
//        sp = getSharedPreferences("com.angelwing.buddyup", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//
//        Bundle buddyInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
//
//        otherUserID = buddyInfo.getString("otherUserID");
//        buddyID = buddyInfo.getString("buddyID");
//        buddyName = buddyInfo.getString("buddyName");
//
//        thisUserID = buddyInfo.getString("thisUserID");
//        thisUserName = buddyInfo.getString("thisUserName");
//
//        bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(bar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(buddyName);



//         Get allMessages from "Conversations" -> buddyID
//        allMessages = new ArrayList<>();
//        convoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Conversations").child(buddyID);
//
//        ListView messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
//        adapter = new ChatArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), allMessages);
//        messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);
//
//        // Add new messages to allMessages
//        convoRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//
//                allMessages.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class));
//                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
//
//            }
//        });
    }

    public void send(View view)
    {
        Log.i("Clicked", "Yuppers");
//        String chat = typeField.getText().toString();
//        chat = truncate(chat);
//
//        Message newMessage = new Message(thisUserName, chat, thisUserID);
//        convoRef.push().setValue(newMessage);
//
//        typeField.setText("");
    }

    public String truncate (String str)
    {
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean profileClicked (MenuItem item)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean settingsClicked (MenuItem item)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean signOutClicked (MenuItem item)
    {
        sp.edit().putBoolean("signedIn", false).apply();

//        auth.signOut();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
}
```

My activity extends AppCompatActivity, if that's important.

Once I click the back button to make the keyboard disappear, I can't make it reappear when I click inside the EditText. Another thing I can't do is move the cursor when I tap inside a String I've already written so if I messed up somewhere, I have to delete text and retype. It's just so frustrating because I have an EditText in another file that works fine and I didn't have to do anything special. The keyboard is opened when I first enter the activity, which is great.

I'm fairly new to Android development so please put things in simple terms, if possible. Thank you so much!

Comment: "Once I click outside of it to make the keyboard disappear, I can't make it reappear when I click inside the EditText"

- What have you done to disappear keyboard?

Comment: Hitting the back button.

Edit: I assumed I was clicking outside, but turns out I'm not lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it may help you solve your problem...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public class AndroidExternalFontsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Made no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: @katie oops.....i cant get your problem correctly so could you please tell what's your exact problem in comment....Thanks!:)

Comment: Sure :) Two problems, both involving EditText:
When I open the activity with the EditText, the keyboard opens and the EditText is focused, so great. I type something in it ("Hello World", for example).

First problem: I can't click inside the string. No matter where I click, the cursor stays at the end of the string, so I can only add text to the end of the string.

Then let's say I click the back button to make the keyboard go away. I now try to bring the keyboard back by focusing on the EditText (clicking inside of it).

Second problem: That ^ doesn't work. I can't get the keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, that's a lot messier that I thought it would be. I had line breaks and stuff but they disappeared heh. Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: That's great katie...may i know which device are you using for simulation?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 6.0.1

Comment: cool...post your code katie because i checked in that device it works fine for me

Comment: I am so, so sorry for wasting your time... I just realized that the mistake was in the xml file. Guess I forgot to change one of the "edittext"s to "typefield" and for whatever reason, didn't get an error.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @Katie..You Won!! :)